# Dependency issue when migrating Teamcity build server

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

I'm migrating a Teamcity server from one VM to another as we're closing the office where the current VM is hosted, I'm doing this by rebuilding the server rather than migrating the VM as there's a bunch of infrastructure differences between the DCs.

The majority of projects are now building fine on the new server however one project is giving me an error. The solution builds ok on my local machine and on the old build server, it's just the new server where I get this build error. The class mentioned in the error message does have a reference to System.Net.Http and is compiling on my local which is what is confusing me.

> \ExceptionHelper.cs(15, 28): error CS1061: 'HttpRequestMessage' does
> not contain a definition for 'CreateResponse' and no accessible
> extension method 'CreateResponse' accepting a first argument of type
> 'HttpRequestMessage' could be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly reference?)

> \ExceptionHelper.cs(31, 28): error CS1061:
> 'HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for
> 'CreateResponse' and no accessible extension method 'CreateResponse'
> accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequestMessage' could be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Could it be because you haven't installed the correct .net version on your new TC server?

Comment: I thought of that so I installed every version of the .Net framework SDK I could get my hands on. The project uses 4.5.2 but I've installed everything from 4.5.2 to 4.8 + .Net 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was MVC 4 wasn't installed.

There was also an additional issue when trying to install it in that the VS 2019 installer doesn't actually install MVC4 if installing to a secondary drive, it will say it has been installed but if you look in the file system the files aren't there. You must use [this standalone installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683) if you want the installation to work properly.